# XCode build error for ZXing phonegap plugin: Undefind symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, zxing

I am trying to use the BarcodeScanner plugin (from ) with PhoneGap. I have carefully followed the steps in the readme (including those in the ZXing readme) but I still get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZXingWidgetController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BarcodeScanner.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QRCodeReader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BarcodeScanner.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The only part of the instructions that haven't gone entirely to plan was this:

> 1. Locate the "ZXingWidget.xcodeproj" file under "`zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/`". Drag  ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and drop it
>      onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files"  sidebar.  A
>      dialog will appear -- make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and
>      "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project" before clicking "Add".
>      Alternatively you can right-click on you project navigator and select
>      'Add files to "MyProject"'

However, when I drag the .xcodeproj onto my Project I don't get a dialog - it just appears as a 'nested' project. If I go the other route and click 'Add files to "MyProject" the dialog doesn't provide an option for "Relative to Project":

[image: xcode add .xcodeproject dialog]

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong appreciated. I am somewhat unfamiliar with xcode (as are many PhoneGap developers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step from the zxing iphone README that apparently didn't work is Step 2. That's the part that tells Xcode to link your app against the zxing widget library and that's what the linker isn't finding. Try double checking that.

Answer (score 1):

The link for ReadMe is [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README). Please follow and double check the steps. I followed and successfully integrated with my code.